# How to fix 500 error with my svelte firebase + sendgrid email function

Tags: javascript, firebase, sendgrid, svelte

I'm working on a svelte landing page with an input for collecting user email address so I can send an email to them automatically with firebase + sendgrid.

Currently I am getting 500 errors saying: {"error":{"message":"Bad Request","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}

Here is my function definition that I have deployed to firebase:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

// Sendgrid Config
import * as sgMail from '@sendgrid/mail';

const API_KEY = functions.config().sendgrid.key;
const TEMPLATE_ID = functions.config().sendgrid.template;
sgMail.setApiKey(API_KEY);

// Sends email via HTTP. Can be called from frontend code. 
export const genericEmail = functions.https.onCall(async (data) => {

    const msg = {
        to: data.email,
        from: 'ghns1133@gmail.com',
        templateId: TEMPLATE_ID,
        dynamic_template_data: {
            subject: data.subject,
            name: data.text,
        },
    };
    console.log(msg);
    await sgMail.send(msg);

    // Handle errors here

    // Response must be JSON serializable
    // return { success: true };

});
```

and i call it in my svelte app like so:

```
const callable = functions.httpsCallable('genericEmail');
          return callable({ text: 'Sending email with Svelte and SendGrid is fun!', subject: 'Email from Svelte', email: formInput}).then(console.log);
```

Comment: This is a guess but it looks like TEMPLATE_ID is not defined

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I think it is defined. Ill update the code snippet to include more of the script